# Insert integer from a jsp form into a database table?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, insert-statement

See my code below...

```
//connect
//reading params from the form
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String year_prime = request.getParameter("year");
int year = Integer.parseInt(year_prime);

//inserting the params into table Students
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(name,year) values('"+name+"', year)");

//close connection
```

I am trying to get the `year` value, which is an `int`, and insert it into a database table. However I am getting an error, and the INSERT methods only seem to work with `Strings`. Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? I hope you already know that it is generally not a good practice to create & use jdbc connections in JSPs, just a word of caution. It would be helpful if you can give the whole stack-trace of the error or exception. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should have to use `PreapredStatement`. From your post I can see you have incorrect value for `VALUES()` set.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(name,year) values ('" + name + "'," + year ")");
```

It will be easy and safe to perform database operation with PreparedStatement:

```
String sql="insert into students(name,year) values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1,name);
statement.setInt(2,year);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It worked with the syntax: stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(name,year) values ('" + name + "'," + year ")");  :) Well, I use this thing only once in my code, but I'll note the PreparedStatement too, just  in case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following links might help you with the basics and also with a working example:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/statement-object-example.htm

Though I won't recommend and it is also not a general practice to include JDBC connection code in JSP, why? Here is the [Servlets and Jsp Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html) for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made the connections in a java file which I named ConnectionsManager.java. I just call them in JSP. In JSP I call the connect method and, at the end, the close connection method(i.e. I return the connection to that ConnectionsManager). The error is:

Comment: I tried with executeQuery():javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: @KyupaSuria: Edit your question to include the Errors so that others may also see it. Please don't put the exceptions in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a regular `Statement`. Also, use `executeQuery()` instead of `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: I got it(I also read the links you post- THANK you for them): If my primary key(ID in my case) is NOT AUTO INCREMENT, I use this syntax:

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(id,name,year) values(1, '"+name+"', year)");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(id,name,year) values(2, '"+name+"', year)");
...............................
I'll use a loop maybe.

If primary key is AUTO INCREMENT I use this syntax:

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into students(name,year) values('"+name+"', year)");

omitting the "id"

Comment: @carlspring: `executeUpdate()` is the correct method to use in this case (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) and also `PreparedStatement` is recommended as it has a lot of benefit but in this case a `Statement` will also do.

Comment: @PrakashK, while you may indeed be right about the `executeUpdate()`, and while I certainly agree you can go with a regular `Statement`, using a `PreparedStatement` would be much more reasonable in terms of security, as you will avoid possible SQL-injection attacks, as this is a JSP page which means that it is possible to pass in maliciously devised unescaped values which can compromise your system. So, I would strongly recommend avoiding regluar `Statements`, unless you're using them internally, from a scope which does not allow the outside world to affect your values.

Comment: @PrakashK: Also, concerning the `executeQuery()` / `executeUpdate()` -- my JDBC knowledge is a bit rusty, as, nowadays, most of us are using frameworks like Hibernate. :)